# Create relationship lookup tables using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large table (below) which im looking to split up in order to reduce load on my DB. Ideally I would take a wide table and create multiple small tables. Im using python 3 and pandas!

| Name | Age | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 20 | London |
| Josh | 18 | Paris |
| Mike | 20 | Paris |

From the table above Im looking to create these 3 tables

| Name | Age | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 1 | 1 |
| Josh | 2 | 2 |
| Mike | 1 | 2 |

| ID | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 18 |

| ID | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | London |
| 2 | Paris |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Moving the city to a different table is fine, but the age is not going to save you anything.

Comment: We have over 200 columns and they are all text so its worth doing

Comment: For age: the encoding is just going to be as duplicative as the keys.  If you have users with ages 18 to 100, you will have keys 1 to 83.  You are not really saving anything.

Comment: Yes, age is an example - we collect 1.5M rows a day with 213 text columns which dont change to much day to day. If I can get its working it would have huge savings

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty simple. For each column, create a mapping of unique items to the unique items' indexes.

```
cols = ['Age', 'City']
mappings = {col: dict(zip(df[col].unique(), np.arange(df[col].nunique()) + 1)) for col in cols}
inverted_mappings = {col: {v: k for k, v in mp.items()} for col, mp in mappings.items()}
```

Now, use `.replace` to apply the lookup dictionaries to the dataframe:

```
>>> df
   Name  Age    City
0   Tom   20  London
1  Josh   18   Paris
2  Mike   20   Paris

>>> new_df = df.replace(mappings)
>>> new_df
   Name  Age  City
0   Tom    1     1
1  Josh    2     2
2  Mike    1     2

>>> new_df.replace(inverted_mappings)
   Name  Age    City
0   Tom   20  London
1  Josh   18   Paris
2  Mike   20   Paris
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Categorical, here is the example:

```
df[['Age','City']] = df[['Age','City']].astype('category')
df = df.assign(Age_id=df.Age.cat.codes+1, City_id=df.City.cat.codes+1)

   Name Age    City  Age_id  City_id
0   Tom  20  London       2        1
1  Josh  18   Paris       1        2
2  Mike  20   Paris       2        2

age_id = df[['Age_id','Age']].drop_duplicates().set_index('Age_id').sort_index()

       Age
Age_id    
1       18
2       20

city_id = df[['City_id','City']].drop_duplicates().set_index('City_id').sort_index()

           City
City_id        
1        London
2         Paris
```